# Application next to Spotlight

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am looking to create an application that I can keep next to Spotlight.

Application like Dropbox, Mint, Alfred reside there and live through out the life of OS.

Where should I start?

Thanks in advance,
RKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSStatusBar` class.

```
NSStatusBar *mStatusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain]; // Retain
[mStatusItem setHighlightMode:YES];
    //Set Menu Icon
[mStatusItem setImage: [NSImage imageNamed:@"Image"]];
[mStatusItem setAlternateImage: [NSImage imageNamed:@"AImage"]];
[mStatusItem setMenu: lMenu];
[mStatusItem setToolTip:@"my app"];
```

Comment: Thats the term I was looking for. Status Bar. But, will this die when I quit my app ? I want to be able to be alive till my OS is alive. See this is the only thing I want in my app.

Comment: Or other way of putting this is; How do I make sure that this app is launched every time I launch my OS, without having user to set this manually?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a "menu extra"/"status bar item".

The official API for status bar items is NSStatusBar; see [Apple's information on status bars](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073-BCIGICBC).

The unofficial (and thus not guaranteed to continue to work, or even to work at all on the latest OS X) internal interface for menu extras is NSMenuExtra; see, for example, [this information on NSMenuExtra](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000078.php).